# Procedure to upgrade to TLS 1.2 for .NET 4.5 and Authorize.net

Tags: .net, azure, authorize.net, tls1.2

I've developed my website using .NET 4.5. I've used authorize.net for payments. 
Recently I got a mail from Authorize.net that they have disabled support for 
TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and require TLS 1.2. I've no idea about TLS and how to upgrade it.
Please tell me the procedure to upgrade to TLS 1.2 which will also be supported on azure as well.

Comment: You mean 4.5.2. TLS 1.2 was added in .NET 4.5.2. Just change your target framework version to a new one, eg 4.6 or later. *Have* you tried changing the target version? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: BTW the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

We just went through this with Paypal and our .Net stuff.  We run on .NET 4.6, so TLS 1.2 was set by default.  In .NET 4.5, TLS 1.2 is supported, but not enabled by default.  you will need to set the `SecurityProtocalType`([MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager(v=vs.100).aspx)) to `Tls12` in your applications.

Judging from Authorize.net's [changelog](http://developer.authorize.net/api/system_changes/), it woud appear that they have disabled TLS 1.0 & 1.1 in their "sandbox" environment.  Therefore, you can use that sandbox to test your code in, to make sure that it works.

Comment: You probably mean 4.5.2. TLS 1.2 was added in .NET 4.5.2. It's **NOT** supported in .NET 4.5 at all

Comment: Besides, a *lot* of companies have issued about disabling anything less than TLS1.2 in the 2-3 years. A lot of (very big) services already demand TLS1.2

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is running 4.5 or 4.5.2, but all the documentation that I've found points to 4.5 and above.  Do you have some documentation stating its only 4.5.2 and above? Obviously another option is to upgrade to the latest framework, but that's not always possible, and perhaps not necessary depending on the application.

Comment: Check the documentation again. It's 4.5.2, the earliest supported .NET version. You'll see that all documentation pages mention 4.5.2 as the earliest version. Besides, there's no reason to use an *unsupported* .NET version

Comment: Fair enough.  I couldn't find anything explicitly stating it was introduced at 4.5.2 (but then again, I couldn't find anything saying that it wasn't, and I wasn't even a developer in that time period).  Appreciate the comments and the point about 4.5 support being deprecated drives the point home for the OP to upgrade if that is what he is using.  I'll update my post.

Comment: Just for kicks I was browsing through Microsoft's new documentation site, and was able to track down the specific documentation for 4.5, which lists 'Tls 12' as a 'SecurityProtocolType'. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netframework-4.5

Comment: Are you sure you did? The new documentation site was created long after 4.5.2 came out. You may be seeing documentation for the new version returned by default when an invalid tag was used. Can you *find* this tag in a machine with only 4.5 installed? Meaning, that Windows Update never run to install a newer version? Can you *use* it? And why would you care if it's unsupported anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You just use below code to resolve this problem:

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: .NET 4.5 doesn't support TLS1.2. That was added in .NET 4.5.2, the earliest supported version